# Can anyone help me with tweet button?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I have some question related to tweet button. In my website, when user click on tweet button, twitter box will popup and default text is place in that twitter box and user can change it up to what they want.

**Here is code**

```
$id=1;
$tweet="Hello world";

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" id="'.$id.'"
data-text="'.$tweet.'" data-lang="ja" data-size="large" data-count="none"
data-url="none">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

**What I want**

When user click on tweet button, then twitter box will popup with default text "Hello world". For the code above, user can change text from "Hello world" to what they want. In fact, i don't want user to change that text.

Can you tell me any solutions about this problem?

Comment: Problem, what problem? There's a problem? What's the "problem"?

Comment: you want to tell the user what they can tweet? how about whar they eat or think to?

Comment: 16x questions and 1x accepted answer. Like I'm going to spend precious time in trying to figure out what you want. Find something that works and modify it to suit. One has to wonder "who" upvoted this "Q".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no way you can stop the user from changing that text, if this was allowed then applications could have tweeted anything on behalf of user and he would have no control on his own tweet.